# How to build subset query using a loop in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset a big table across a number of columns, so all the rows where `State_2009`, `State_2010`, `State_2011` etc. do not equal the value "Unknown."

My instinct was to do something like this (coming from a JS background), where I either build the query in a loop or continually subset the data in a loop, referencing the year as a variable.

```
mysubset <- data
for(i in 2009:2016){
  mysubset <- subset(mysubset, paste("State_",i," != Unknown",sep=""))
}
```

But this doesn't work, at least because `paste` returns a string, giving me the error `'subset' must be logical`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: could you `head(data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr with the filter_ function should get you the correct output

```
library(dplyr)

mysubset <- data

for(i in 2009:2016)
{
  mysubset <- mysubset %>%
              filter_(paste("State_",i," != \"Unknown\"", sep = ""))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Matt's answer, you could also do it like this:

```
cols     <- paste0( "State_", 2009:2016)
inds     <- which( mysubset[ ,cols] == "Unknown", arr.ind = T)[,1]
mysubset <- mysubset[-(unique(inds), ]
```